# Django contact form with out requiring credentials

Tags: python, django, django-forms

my first question here, quite a a simple one I hope. I am wondering if there are any acceptable ways to create a simple contact form for clients to send an email directly to me. The current method I am using requires me to input my password into settings.py which I cannot understand why, surely this isn't necessary.

I cannot seem to find any other methods using search engines.

Comment: Skip the form, use a `mailto:` link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not that simple. Without authentication how mail server will know?
you cant create your own form of gmail `for User to Send you an Email`.
You can do create form in which user will submit there details and they will get email as a response from your email which is set in your `settings.py` which ofc requires password.

there is a simple alternative you can use which wont use your contact form but it will use user's default mail system.
you can use html's `mailto` attribute.

Comment: There are ways in which you can use plugins on wordpress  for contact forms that only require an email address as input. So I don't understand why I am forced to ask for a clients credentials just to receive emails

Comment: @DavidHenson if I use your email as a receiver, make a form, and publish it without your concern. is that allowed? You sure?

Comment: @DavidHenson You will always need SMTP configuration in your project to setup a mail account as a sender.
I cannot just enter anyone's email address in the form and send it to you.